# merge two different lists one is of wifi type other is of bluetooth type

Tags: java, list, generics, arraylist

The problem is simple yet generic. what i want to achieve is i want to make a list that will will be merge of two different lists one is of type Wifi and the other is of type bluetooth.

```java
List<WifiModel> wifiList = [new WifiModel(), new WifiModel()]

List<Bluetooth> bluetoothList = [new BluetoothModel(), new BluetoothModel()]

List<ResultModel> result = [new WifiModel(), new BluetoothModel(), new WifiModel()]
```

well as I've described in my code snippet this is what i want to achive. To merge two lists into one final result list. Can anybody guide me on this. Thanks!

Comment: Are these three classes yours? We don't know the relationship between them and need more info

Comment: If WifiModel and Bluetooth both subclass ResultModel, you can just `result.addAll(wifiList); result.addAll(bluetoothList);`

Comment: @bcr666 i will try it and let you know. Thanks

Comment: we can subclass the bluetooth model but wifimodel is actually ScanResult class in the android sdk. and the constructor is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

What do the Wifi and bluetooth have in common and what are you going to use them for?

If they both have common functionality that you want to access then you could move it to an abstract class or interface and create a list of the interface instead.

```
class Scratch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Bluetooth> bluetoothList = new ArrayList<>();
        bluetoothList.add(new Bluetooth());

        List<Wifi> wifiList = new ArrayList<>();
        wifiList.add(new Wifi());

        List<Connectable> connectables = new ArrayList<>();
        connectables.addAll(bluetoothList);
        connectables.addAll(wifiList);

        connectables.forEach(item -> item.connect());

        System.out.println("Finished");
    }

}

class Bluetooth extends Connectable {

}

class Wifi extends Connectable {

}

abstract class Connectable {

    public boolean connect(){
        System.out.println("Connected");
        return true;
    }

}
```

If you are returning to a consumer then id suggest keeping them separate and having a Object that has fields for both lists.

```
class SearchDeviceResults {

    List<Bluetooth> yada....
    List<Wifi> tada....

}
```

Comment: Finally you can just make the list without generics List giveMeAnything = new ArrayList() The reason this isnt normally done is that it is easy to break and hard to follow.

Comment: Hi Pete thanks for your help but ScanResult is a class used to derive results of wifi scan and that class constructor is hidden. I know by reflection we can access that function but we are not going to create complexity here. one solution that's working is using Object class as a ResultModel to add BluetoothModel and WifiModel lists data. Thanks!